# Throwing OutofMemory when setting Bitmap again

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

I'm using a menu where users can select a category to show. Once a category starts , I'm loading a layer over the background and use this as the resource of my `GestureImageView`. This works perfectly, but when I do this a couple of times. Going back and forth between the category selection and the map, it throws an `OutOfMemory Exception`.

This is the method used to create the `GestureImageView`. The bgverkenning drawable is in every drawable map and sizes are according to 4:6:8:12 (mdpi - hdpi - xhdpi - xxhdpi).

```
private void loadImageFromStorage(String path, String name)
{

    try {

        File f=new File(path, name);
        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        options.inSampleSize=2;
    //    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,options);

        BitmapFactory.Options options2=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options2.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

        Drawable laag = new BitmapDrawable(b);
        Bitmap back = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bgverkenning, options2);

        Drawable bg = new BitmapDrawable(back);
        Drawable [] lagen = {bg,laag};
        LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(lagen);
        map.setImageDrawable(ld);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When the activity is stopped, the drawable is deleted.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Drawable d = map.getDrawable();
    if(d!=null) d.setCallback(null);
    map.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mention before you should use a library. I would recommend Glide its easy to use. 
[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/README.md) [LayerDrawable with Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/245)

Comment: Although I like this solution, I can't figure out how to use a LayerDrawable like solution and in the topic you mentioned, they used 2 imageviews on top of each other, which will not work in my case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Bitmaps are really heavy for android. Consider using this library for setting pictures:
https://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Java file

roundBitmap.recycle();

Comment: When should I use this? When calling onStop?